# Add/Remove Class in header column in GridView ASP.NET from code behind file

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with accessible headers that can choose options from drop down. I have a function in jquery to avoid sorting on applying noSort class on header. I basically want that if Count of rows in GridView is greater than 500, it should add class noSort on GridView headers on drop down selected index change and if less than that then it should remove noSort from header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, call below function on Databound event of gridview that will be called each time gridview data changes so the header columns can be individually broken down:

```
if (gvName.Rows.Count > sortingLimit)  //Check for rowcount for limit before sorting
        {
            gvName.HeaderRow.Cells[0].CssClass = "noSort fieldAlignCenter";
            gvName.HeaderRow.Cells[1].CssClass = "noSort";
            gvName.HeaderRow.Cells[2].CssClass = "noSort";
            gvName.HeaderRow.Cells[3].CssClass = "noSort";
            gvName.HeaderRow.Cells[4].CssClass = "noSort";
            gvName.HeaderRow.Cells[5].CssClass = "noSort";
            gvName.HeaderRow.Cells[7].CssClass = "noSort";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of gridviews "Header Style" property..:)

Once after loading the data into the grid, make sure, you run the following snippet like:(Assuem id of the gridview as gvSagar):

gvSagar.HeaderStyle.CssClass="requiredClassName";